# ReactJs - Horizontal Mobile Menu using ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs

**Mobile Menu UI: (PanelGroup shared with ancestor & descendant components)**

1. Inital MenuPanel passes a PanelGroup (with an navItems array in props) to the DOM.
2. Some of the navItems passed have subNavItems.
3. Those with subNavItems also pass a PanelGroup with its children to the DOM.

**What is expected to happen:**

1. When the MenuPanel is triggered navItems are listed and those with subNavItems have a marker for the user to click to reveal the subNavItems.
2. When subNavItems are selected, all previous navItems are to disappear and only the subNavItems display.

**Desired Result: Items up the chain disappear & selected child nodes appear after Family Law navItem is clicked**

[image]

**Actual Result: Items up the chain remain and selected child nodes write ontop of them after Family Law navItem is clicked**

[image]

**MobileNavButton: (the blue menu button above)**

export default class MobileNavButton extends Component {

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMobileMenuGroup: false
    }
  }

  static propTypes = {
    btn: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    viewDevice: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  handleShowHide(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const doesShow = !this.state.showMobileMenuGroup;
    this.setState({showMobileMenuGroup: doesShow});
  }

  render() {
    const { btn, viewDevice } = this.props;
    return (
      <section>
           .....
        { btn.clickEvent ?
          <li ref="menuButton">
            <a onClick={ this.handleShowHide.bind(this) }>
              <icon className={ btn.icon }/>
              <h2>{ btn.innerText }</h2>
            </a>
            <MobileMenuPanel childPages={ btn.childPages } showMobileMenuGroup={ this.state.showMobileMenuGroup } />
          </li> : ''
        }
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

**MenuPanel:**

```
export default class MobileMenuPanel extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    childPages: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    showMobileMenuGroup: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { showMobileMenuGroup } = this.props;
    const { childPages } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className='imenupanel' style={showMobileMenuGroup ? showSlide : hideSlide } >
        <MobileMenuGroup childPages={ childPages } showMobileMenuGroup={showMobileMenuGroup ? true : false } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**MobileMenuGroup:**

```
export default class MobileMenuGroup extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    childPages: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    showMobileMenuGroup: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { childPages } = this.props;
    const { showMobileMenuGroup } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className='imenu' style={  showMobileMenuGroup ? { display: 'block' } : { display: 'none' } }>
        {
          childPages.map((childPage, idx) => {
            return (
              <MobileNavMenuItem key={ idx } menuItem={ childPage }/>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**MobileNavMenuItem:**

```
export default class MobileNavMenuItem extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMobileMenuGroup: false
    }
  }

  static propTypes = {
    menuItem: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  showChildren(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let showMobileMenuGroup = !this.state.showMobileMenuGroup;
    this.setState({ showMobileMenuGroup: showMobileMenuGroup });
  }

  render() {
    const { menuItem } = this.props;
    const childPages = menuItem.childPages !== undefined ? menuItem.childPages.length : 0;
    let menuItemsStyle = childPages > 0 ? 'imenuitem iright' : 'imenuitem'
    return (
          <div className={ menuItemsStyle } pageId={ menuItem.pageId } childPages={ childPages }
            >
            { childPages > 0 ?
            <span onClick={ this.showChildren.bind(this) } >
                <div style={ { color: '#FFFFFF', padding: '12px 15px' } }>{ menuItem.title }</div>
              <MenuPanelGroup childPages={ menuItem.childPages } showMobileMenuGroup={ this.state.showMobileMenuGroup } />
              </span>
              :
              <a href={ menuItem.linkTo }>{ menuItem.title }</a>
            }
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I went with ReactCSSTransitionGroup**

[image]

**Here is sample code that achieved my goals:**

**Index.js**

```
//    "react": "^0.14.7",
//    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^0.14.7",
//    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
const ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group')
```

---

```
const SlideTransition = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    depth: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    name: React.PropTypes.string
  },
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      name: 'slider'
    };
  },
  getInitialState() {
    return {direction: 'right'};
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    const direction = newProps.depth > this.props.depth ? 'right' : 'left';
    this.setState({direction});
  },
  render() {
    const {name, depth} = this.props;
    const outerProps = {
      className: `${name}-outer-wrapper ${this.props.className}`
    };
    console.log(`name: ${name} depth: ${depth}`);
    const transProps = {
      component: 'div',
      transitionName: `${name}-${this.state.direction}`,
      className: `${name}-transition-group`
    };
    const innerProps = {
      ref: 'inner',
      key: depth,
      className: `${name}-inner-wrapper` // imenupanel
    };

    return <div {...this.props} {...outerProps}>
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}  {...transProps}>
        <div {...innerProps}>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>;
  }
});
```

---

```
const Browser = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      path: []
    }
  },
  navUp() {
    this.setState({path: this.state.path.slice(0, -1)})
  },
  navDown(index) {
    this.setState({path: this.state.path.concat(index)})
  },
  render() {
    const {path} = this.state;
    const items = path.reduce(function(items, key) {
      return items[key].children;
    }, this.props.items);
    console.log(path);
    console.log(this.props.items);
    return <div className="browser">

      <SlideTransition depth={path.length} className="items-container">
        <div className="menuItem">{path.length > 0 ? <a style={ { color: 'white' } }  onClick={this.navUp}>Back</a> : 'Home'}</div>
        {items.map(function(item, index) {
          if (item.children) {
            return <div key={item.name} style={ { clear: 'both' } } className="menuItem" >
              <a style={ { display: 'inline!Important', color: 'white' } } href="#">{item.name}</a>
              <a style={ { display: 'inline!Important', float: 'right', background: 'transparent' } } className="arrow" onClick={e => this.navDown(index)} key={item.name}>&nbsp;</a></div>;
          } else {
            return <div className="menuItem" key={item.name} key={item.name}><a href="#"style={ { color: 'white' } }>{item.name}</a></div>;
          }
        }.bind(this))}
      </SlideTransition>

    </div>;
  }
});
```

---

```
const data = [
  {name: 'Animal', children: [
    {name: 'Land', children: [
      {name: 'Cheetah'},
      {name: 'Ant'},
    ]},
    {name: 'Air', children: [
      {name: 'Eagle'}
    ]},
    {name: 'Water', children: [
      {name: 'Water 1', children: [{name: 'Level'}]},
      {name: 'Water 2', children: [
        {name: 'Water 2', children: [
          {name: 'Water 2 -1'},
          {name: 'Water 2 -2', children: [
            {name: 'Water 2-2-1'},
            {name: 'Water 2-2 -2'},
            {name: 'Water 2-2-3'}
          ]},
          {name: 'Water 2 -3'}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]}
  ]},
  {name: 'Vegetable', children: [
    {name: 'Broccoli'},
    {name: 'IE6'},
  ]},
  {name: 'Mineral', children: [
    {name: 'Granite'},
    {name: 'Uraninite'},
  ]},
];

render(<Browser items={data} />, document.getElementById('MobileNav'));
```

**index.html styles**

```
   <style>
        a {
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            color:#fff;
        }

        .items-container {
            max-width: 20rem;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            border-radius: .25rem;
        }

        .arrow {
            padding: .25rem .5rem;
        }

        .menuItem {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 15px;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #5a5a5a;
            padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
        }

        a.arrow:after {
            content: '\e0ea';
            color: #fff;
            font-family: 'icomoon-ult';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: none;
        }

        a.item:hover {
            background: #eee;
        }

        /* Generic slider styles */

        .slider-outer-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: max-height .2s ease-in;
        }

        .slider-transition-group {
            width: 200%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .slider-inner-wrapper {
            background-color: #000;
            width: 50%;
            float: right;
            transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
            height: 400px;
        }

        .slider-inner-wrapper:first-child {
            position: relative;
            left: -50%;
        }

        .slider-right-enter {
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        }

        .slider-left-enter {
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        }

        .slider-right-enter-active,
        .slider-left-enter-active,
        .slider-right-leave,
        .slider-left-leave {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        .slider-right-leave-active {
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        }

        .slider-left-leave-active {
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        }
    </style>
```